# Not able to install postgresql in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I tried many times installing postgresql in Ubuntu 14.04 without success.

I keep getting the following error:

> Can't exec "/tmp/postgresql-common.config.WJ3dGb": Permission denied at /usr/share/perl/5.18/IPC/Open3.pm line 173.

I changed the permissions of `/tmp` and `Open3.pm` to execute (`chmod 744`) without success.

Comment: edit the question and add the output of these commands. the same user should be used: `df` and `df /tmp/postgresql-common.config.WJ3dGb` and `ls -l /tmp/postgresql-common.config.WJ3dGb` and `mount`

Comment: edit the question and add the line 103 of the /usr/share/perl/5.18/IPC/Open3.pm file: `awk 'NR==103{print;exit}' /usr/share/perl/5.18/IPC/Open3.pm`